# How to specify the line under cursor in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to count number of occurrences of the line under the cursor. I intend to do it with the

```
:%s/pattern/&/gn
```

command. So how do I specify the line under cursor in place of `pattern`?

Comment: I'd usually do `%w!sort | unique -dc | less` or `%!sort|unique -c` and undo

Answer (score 3):

You can insert the current line via the *expression register*. For a literal match, switch the regular expression to *very nomagic* mode (`\V`), and escape any backslashes and the separator in the line:

```
:%s/\V<C-r>=escape(getline('.'), '/\')<CR>/&/gn
```

Depending on what you want to count exactly, you may also need to anchor (`\^...\$` in very nomagic mode) the pattern.

Instead of direct insertion via `<C-r>`, you can also build the command via `:execute`. This is more suitable in a function.

```
:execute '%s/\V' . escape(getline('.'), '/\') . '/&/gn'
```

Comment: A middle ground is to _yank_ the current line (`Y` or `yy`) and use it like `:%s/\V<C-r>"`, in which case you'd have to use vigilance to spot any hazardous escape characters. It is a lot quicker for one-offs, though

Comment: I kind of agree with sehe. How these solutions are simpler than yanking and then specifying the register using `<C-r>"`?

Comment: I wouldn't type those repeatedly. If I needed this more often, I'd naturally create a mapping or command for it. You didn't tell us what you use this for...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a canned plugin solution, my [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634) can count occurrences. With it, `V<A-m>` will show a summary like this:

```
On sole match in this line, 8 following, 2 in previous lines; total 10 for /this line\n/
```